# Blocking all Windows Internet access from a Win32 app

Tags: c++, windows, networking, winapi

What would be the simplest way for an application I'm writing to block all Internet access on a Windows machine?

More details:

Windows: XP or higher

Application: A basic Win32 app written in C/C++.

Blocking: It needs to be able to block and unblock at will, ideally in a way that the user can't easily reverse. (By, say, right clicking on a network connection icon in the system tray.) Also, ideally, I'd like the method it uses to allow access to be restored should the user restart Windows or reset the machine, though I'd also be willing to have the app auto launch with Windows and unblock access upon startup if the machine was reset while in a blocked state.

Internet access: Primarily, I'd like to block conventional browsers from hitting conventional http/https sites. Secondarily, it would be nice to block IM clients and client-side social networking apps. It would also be nice, but not required, to still allow local networking for file sharing, etc. (Note that only the first requirement is absolute.)

Final notes: This is not meant to be a security utility, nor will its relationship to the user be adversarial (as, for example, with a parental control utility) so it's not important for it to use a scheme that can't be worked around by a determined user. (Consider that I intend for a reboot or reset to clear the blocking. This means that any workaround a user might discover that would take more effort than this is okay.)

Thanks!

p.s. I suspect that the Windows Firewall API won't work for me because this needs to work for users that haven't enabled the firewall or don't have admin privileges, but I'll be thrilled if I'm corrected on this.

Comment: Please note that you are inherently exploiting an OS weakness. As such, you will likely have to address each SP of each Windows version. As you correctly note, the "fix network" function exists, and you simply cannot expect to trump that.

Comment: Oh, and please make it quite obvious that the program is installed. I.e. do create a modal messagebox stating that "ACME network blocker has blocked a connection to 'updates.microsoft.com'". This program will cause a lot of confusion anyway, best not to do so by hiding it. I'll know I'll flag my software as being incompatible with such an app regardless.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're intending to run applications that you don't *want* to access the internet. Perhaps you could run them inside a virtual machine such as VirtualBox with networking disabled.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with a Winsock [SPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741418%28VS.85%29.aspx). The [Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e6e1c3df-a74f-4207-8586-711ebe331cdc&displaylang=en) has a sample (under Samples\netds\winsock\lsp) which implements what is called a layered service provider which allows you to hook all the user mode functions provided by Winsock and reject/modify the calls to block network access or redirect traffic to different locations. All installed winsock applications will be affected, so in your code you could have policys for what applications can go out and the like and disabled/enable on the fly. Now a determined person could find ways around this but it would be a pain.

That said this isn't *trivial* to do but the sample should get you most of the way there.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot effectively or practically write your tool with only a user mode application.

What you need to write is a network I/O stack filter driver.  This done by writing a Windows Driver.  This is different from a Windows Win32 application.   Drivers run in kernel mode and applications run in user mode.

On Windows Vista and later, the kernel mode Network Programming Interface (NPI) is designed for this.    This is the same API that Windows Firewalls use.  These are sometimes called the Winsock kernel (WSK) APIs.

In effect, you are writing a network firewall (more or less)

here are some links

- **[Introduction to Winsock Kernel (WSK)](http://blogs.msdn.com/wndp/archive/2006/02/24/538746.aspx)**
- **[Windows Core Networking Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/wndp/default.aspx)**
- **[The Network Programming Interface Docs on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa504034.aspx)**

Note, your will likely need at least two components

1. Your driver
2. A Graphical application that a person can use to control your tool

If you want to do any monitoring, you will likely need a user mode service that collects data from your driver.   This works better than trying to do this in the driver.   In general, you should do the minimal amount of work in the driver.

A few notes:

1. You need to be very conscious of security when writing this kind of software.  This is very much non trivial.  Software that is network facing has the highest security requirements.
2. Be cognizant of performance.
3. Your driver and/or service must be aware of the context of a calling application.  This is also a security boundary.   For example, an application not running as administrator should not be able to control your driver.

Answer (score -2):

take a look at firewall sourcecodes